# java pdfbox get image dimensions in page and scale image down

Tags: java, pdf, compression, pdfbox

I am working on code to reduce the size of pdf file by reducing the image size to get the pdf to be less than a threshold of 1 MB. I have two questions.

1. An image original size may be 1600 x 2400 px, but it is displayed on the page on lower left hand corner for 200 x 300 px. In that case, when I extract the image, I get 1600 x 2400 px, How do I determine the dimensions of the image drawn on the page. In this case, how do I get the numbers 200 x 300 px so that I can scale down the image to that size and display it so that quality is not too bad. I have looked at the example of  PrintImageLocations.java in pdfbox examples but that tells me only the pixel size of actual image and always prints displayed size as 1.0 in user space units. I have been searching without any luck for methods that will give me displayed size of the image in pixels
2. Once the image dimensions displayed on the page are determined, how can I compress the image with these target dimensions so that the image size is reduced without losing the quality too much.

I have been going over the examples and searching all around without much help. Any pointers or samples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *how can I compress the image with these target dimensions so that the image size is reduced without losing the quality too much* How can I both have my cake and eat my cake?

Comment: I would look at the compression algorithm first, as going from 1600x2400 to 200x300 is a HUGE loss of information. Assuming your image is a photo, you would want at least DCT (JPEG), or possibly JPX (JPEG2000) compression. There are other compressions supported by PDF if your image data is a particular type, like mono or greyscale document scan. Also For DCT(JPEG) compression it's possible to adjust the quality.

Comment: Can you share your example pdf? `PrintImageLocations` used to have some issues but they have been worked on...

Comment: @mkl, I was hoping this thread gets your attention as I had seen a lot of very helpful answers from you in the past. pdf link is http://www3.weforum.org/docs/White_Paper_Incredible_India_2_0_final_.pdf. When I run PrintImageLocations.java from pdf-box 2.0.9, I get the following for all the images in PDF.
displayed size  = 1.0, 1.0 in user space units
displayed size  = 0.013888889, 0.013888889 in inches at 72 dpi rendering
displayed size  = 0.35277778, 0.35277778 in millimeters at 72 dpi rendering

Comment: I just ran `PrintImageLocations` from the current 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT version of PDFBox. Here I get four outputs of about `displayed size  = 96.79599, 67.75231 in millimeters at 72 dpi rendering` on the first page. I know that `PrintImageLocations` was broken in some 2.0.x version but I'd have thought it to be fixed by now. You might want to use the `PrintImageLocations` class from the development code to derive your code from.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for your response. I will check out the 3.0 version, How do I get the displayed pixel size from this millimeters or user space units. Assuming dpi is pixels per inch, how can I determine if the document has 72 dpi or 300 dpi. Is there any API call for it ?

Comment: The version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT `PrintImageLocations` also outputs sensible results *in user space units* and *in inches at 72 dpi rendering*.